# Example of Metric Space which is homeomorphic to itself equipped with the discrete metric

Tags: real-analysis

I'm currently working on a homework problem in which I am supposed to prove something given the conditions that a metric space M is homeomorphic to itself equipped with the discrete metric. In order to better picture this I have been trying to come up with examples in which the original metric is not the discrete metric but I have failed to do so.

Can anyone provide me with a few examples that are not too complicated to play around with and get a better feel for the concept?

Thanks.

Comment: can you think of  examples of two metric spaces which are homeomorphic to discrete metric space?

Comment: No that's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: in the definition of discrete metric, change the distance between different points to be 2. what you get?

Comment: I believe that you and John Ma are getting at the same point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about if the original metric $d$ on $X$ is given by $d = C d_0$, where $C>0$ and $d_0$ is the discrete metric?

Or take any discrete set in $\mathbb R^n$, call that $X$ and give it the subspace metric $d(x, y) = |x-y|$.

Comment: So then we have a bijection in the form of $f(x)=\frac{1}{C} x$?

Comment: Note that the identity map $(X, d) \to (X, d_0)$ is a homeomorphism